# How to implement a key-key or value-value type data structure

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, key

I am looking for a way to group letters, such that a letter in a group when called might invoke and return another character in the same group. Very much similar to the dictionary data structure except that all values in the couple acts **as both key and value.**

G1 = {a,b}

G2 = {c,d}

What can be the easiest way to write a function `f` where

1. `f(a)` returns `b`
2. `f(b)` returns `a`

I am particularly trying to avoid the below type dictionary

```
{"a":"b", "b":"a", "c","d", "d":"c"}
```

because

1. redundancy on large scale
2. also `a` and `b` can be multi letter strings, can be so large

Preferably Python, or for that reason programming language independent solution is welcomed. Maybe I am unaware of any existing data structure implementation.

Comment: I don't think there's anything that can do this efficiently other than the redundant dictionary.

Comment: What should `f(a)` return in these cases: (1) `G1 = {a, b, c}` (2) `G1 = {a, b}; G2 = {a, c}`?

Comment: Does every group contain exactly two elements?

Comment: I think using a dictionary with redundancy (as you proposed yourself) is not as bad as it sounds. It won’t waste much space, even if the strings are large, because the dictionary only holds references to the strings. For example: `a="foo"; b="bar"; d={a: b; b: a}` In this case, the strings “foo” and “bar” will only be in memory once.

Comment: thanks, for the comments, yeah definitely a couple

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want, so I can't write a decent answer, but it seems like a good answer would have something to do with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: g1 ={a,b,c}; then function(b) is expected to return {a,b}
but i would like to limit this topic to only couples

Comment: i can very well go with regular little redundant dictionary, but the point of raising this question is just i am curious if any easy datastructure that when given a memeber of any group, return another member of a group. just like friends when caught redhanded, point and involve another otherwise uncaught friend too in the act

Comment: If you're only worried about couples, then you would just use the dictionary.  It does NOT really waste a lot of space as long as you use the *same* string in both the key and value positions.

Comment: @inof: The strings will be in memory only once, in any case.  Python compliers apply the basic optimization of constant folding.  Each reference to "foo" will have the same `id()`.

Answer (score 1):

The deal here depends on whether you want to spare time or space.

If you want speed, then there's no better solution than the redundant dictionary you want to avoid (as far as I know). With that solution, you have O(2n) in space complexity and O(logn) in time complexity.

But if you prefer not to have redundant data and don't mind a linear search, you can use a regular dictionary with a modified lookup function. Something like this, in Python.

```py
def lookup(d, x):
  y = d.get(x, None)
  if y is None:
    for k in d:
      if d[k] == x:
        y = k
        break
  return y

data = {
  'a': 'b',
  'c': 'd'
}

print(lookup(data, 'a')) # output: b
print(lookup(data, 'd')) # output: c
```

With this method, you have O(n) in space complexity, half of the searches are O(logn) and the other half are O(n), in time complexity.

Comment: (Thanks for your answer, i am short of reps to upvote yours)
so there are three pairs of unique balls pairs .(red-yellow)(blue-green)(aqua-orange)). Why has one to construct a solution upfront for getting the pair, and no prebuilt ones present in any programming languages that can say if you pick something aqua you also got something orange and vice versa. the vice versa is something i am pondering over for quite some time,
Wasn't there many real life use cases where you have two values in a small group within a bigger group , when one spotted means other too comes up.

Comment: It is not prebuilt because there is not a direct way to implement a intuitive datastructure with that behaviour. The closest thing you will find is something like this (if I'm wrong, someone correct me), and as you see is not exactly the most elegant thing in the world.

Comment: @Pingu I finally remembered the term for this structure: **bimap**. Here you have some useful links: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map), [SO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bimap)

Comment: very well, this looks promising
bidirectional map maybe is the magical nomenclature of my abstraction
will look into it and come with an update

Answer (score -2):

From what little you describe, it seems that you want this functionality:

```
def friend(head):
    # Find the cluster that contains "head"
    # Return another element of that cluster
```

If the clusters are partitions, such that all elements of that cluster are connected to each other, and to no other elements, then sets will do the job nicely.  For instance:

```
import random

G1 = {a,b}
G2 = {c,d}
group_list = [G1, G2]

def friend(head):
    for group in group_list:
        if head in group:
            headless = group - head
            return random.choice(headless)
    # If not found, return None by default
```

**Update for pairs-only use**

If you know that each set has only two elements, then the loop body reduces to

```
        if head in group:
            return group - {head}
```

To facilitate processing, you can build a dict to look up the set from each element.

```
lookup = {k: v for k in v for v in group_list}
```

Then you would find the proper group without the `for` loop.

---

If you have "outside" links, then you have a graph.  Choose a graph package (e.g. `networkx`).  `friend` will look up the neighbors of the given node (a method of the package); you make a random choice from that list.

Comment: i intended g2 just for the purpose of illustration, not anything more.
the same function when [[a:b],[c,d],[e,f]] should return b for a and a for b and so on

Comment: is there an even simpler, and more primitive structure

Comment: More primitive than a set?  Could you perhaps describe the (lack of) properties such a structure would have?

Comment: pls do note that i am just short of reputation to add an upvote, and i am immensely grateful for your answer here; the set is kinda cool solution where the set difference actually puts up the required solution via two steps 1. correct set(say g1) spotting 2. set difference.

Comment: But i am more curious on why there has been no existing data structure like an inbuilt one to cater this purpose, that is if you took an element from a pool, it is chained with another element. say a box with ball couplets cellotaped against each other. so there are three pairs of unique balls.(red-yellow)(blue-green)(aqua-orange)).
Why has one to construct a solution upfront for getting the pair, and no prebuilt ones present in any programming languages that can say if you pick something aqua you also got something orange and vice versa. the vice versa is the secret trick here i am pondering

Comment: That is an abstract discussion you need to take up on an appropriate site, not Stack Overflow.  The short answer is that there isn't much need for such a data structure.  Also note that any 4th-generation language, and many 3rd-generation languages, allow you to define your own structures.

Comment: As for the reputation ... you should still choose a "best answer", so that Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: @Pingu the reason there is no common data structure for this is that nobody ever needs it.  What people do need are indexes -- looking up red, green, or blue would get you the [red, green, blue] triple, from which you could easily remove the one you looked up, if that was your need.

Comment: i'd personally doubt that nobody has needed it. 
a simple thing like a username for login these days, are unique but not limited to one.
which means a person's email address or even a phone number should be(not necessarily) pointing at each other, though the uuids are relationally implemented. 

thanks to @Miguel, for bidirectional mapping nomenclature.
i'm futher into reading these https://github.com/jab/bidict.
where they say "has been used for many years by several teams at Google, Venmo, CERN, Bank of America Merrill Lynch, Bloomberg, Two Sigma, and many others"

Comment: Yes, some people need it.  They write a class to handle it.  Stack Overflow is not the place to debate whether it *should* be a built-in type.